# How to webscrape information with java

Tags: java, string

I've been trying to do a lot of research with webscraping. I'm trying to load the stats of different characters of the game I play into my program, and as there are over 150 of them I can't manually type them all in. Here is one of the pages that I'm trying to scrape information [from this site](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kassadin)

I'm trying to get these variables:
HEALTH, ATTACK DAMAGE, HEALTH REGEN.,ATTACK SPEED, MANA,ARMOR,RANGE,MOV. SPEED

So far what I've gotten is below with the JSoup library which prints the website in a single line of text, and I'm not sure how to extract the variables from that variable.

```
package WebScraper;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class getWikiStats {
        public void getChampStats(){
                try {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kassadin").get();
                        String website = doc.text();
                        System.out.println(website);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there a way to get the variables from that line of text?

Comment: Your question has a pretty large scope, as for someone to answer it, they will have to go examine the HTML structure of the wiki page as well as explain how to use the JSoup library. My recommendation is to view source on the page to determine where the items you are looking for can be found, then read the [JSoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) to understand how to use the library to extract that information.

Comment: There are various browser plugins that can be had for little to no money that would solve your problem, since it seems you're more interested in grabbing data than in creating web scraping software. It's easier to pay to have your pizza delivered than it is to build a car so that you can go pick it up.

Comment: All i'm really asking is how to search a string for a keyword and then get the numbers next to the keyword and store it in a string from which I will then convert to an integer

Comment: java.lang.String.indexOf() gives you the position of particular text; substring() gives you sections of the string given starting and ending positions (or is it starting position and length?  can't remember).  Remember that the string you're searching for may not be unique.